# Grouping two words as one in FreqDist

Tags: python, nltk

My problem is that I have an Excel file with tweet data. I am doing text analysis by plotting frequency distribution of words. The second and the forth most frequent words are 'pakistan' and 'pak' which basically means the same. So I want them to be considered as one and group them. Here is the code:

```
db=pd.read_excel(r'hello world.xlsx')
db['Sentence'] = db['Sentence'].astype(str).str.lower() #convert all text to lower case

regexp = RegexpTokenizer('\w+')
db['Sentence_token']=db['Sentence'].apply(regexp.tokenize)

stopwords = nltk.corpus.stopwords.words("english")
my_stopwords = []
stopwords.extend(my_stopwords)

db['Sentence_token'] = db['Sentence_token'].apply(lambda x: [item for item in x if item not in stopwords])   
db['Sentence_string'] = db['Sentence_token'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join([item for item in x if len(item)>0])) 

all_words = ' '.join([word for word in file['Sentence_string']])

tokenized_words = nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize(all_words)
fdist = FreqDist(tokenized_words)

db['Sentence_string_fdist'] = db['Sentence_token'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join([item for item in x if fdist[item] >= 2])) #drop words which occur less than 2 times
db[['Sentence', 'Sentence_token', 'Sentence_string', 'Sentence_string_fdist']]

fdist
```

Output:

```
FreqDist({'xxx': 870, 'pakistan': 466, 'xxx': 268, 'pak': 253, 'xxx': 253, 'xxx': 251, 'xxx': 237, ...})
```

Comment: please prvide a sample of data to work with.  thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`FreqDist` is a `collections.Counter`, which in turn is a dictionary. So we can use `dict.pop` method to get the value and remove the key at the same time. Let's say, we want to remove `'pak'` and top up the frequency of `'pakistan'` accordingly. To do this we can use something like this:

```
freq['pakistan'] += freq.pop('pak', 0)
```